# How to change the regular expression of an address that violates the Swiftmailer RFC

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to add a function to change the regular expression so as not to throw an exception when using an address that violates RFC in an application that runs on Symfony 4.4.
The only exceptions are consecutive dots and addresses with "." in front of @.
When I was running before Symfony4, I was using "Swift_Mime_Grammar".
This code is not available in Symfony4 and needs to be implemented anew.
Do you have any ideas?

Before Code

```php
public function validator()
{
    $swiftMimeGrammar = \Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()->lookup('mime.grammar');
    $prop = new \ReflectionProperty('\Swift_Mime_Grammar', '_grammar');
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    $_grammar = $prop->getValue($swiftMimeGrammar);
    $_grammar['addr-spec'] = '.*';
    $prop->setValue($swiftMimeGrammar, $_grammar);
}
```